# Cannot set property '' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble with my javascript function.

I'm trying to set a property to a random value.

```
    var spel = new Object();

    function start() {
         spel.antwoord = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
         spel.aantalKeer = 0;

         number.value = "";
         document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = "";
         document.getElementById('hintPos').innerHTML = "";
    }
```

But, I'm getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'antwoord' of undefined`.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? If I alert the `Math.floor` I get a number as expected, so why is it undefined?

Comment: I do not see spel defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: You haven't defined `spel`. Define it as `var spel = {};` before using it.

Comment: `spel` is defined above the function. Forgot to add that

Comment: How/when/where is `start()` called?

Comment: `start()` is called on page load

Comment: I also don't see `number` defined

Comment: If your code really looked like what you posted, you would not get the error. The error means that `spel` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Tushar `number` is also defined above the function. `number` is a button in my HTML

Comment: @Pointy I really don't know what's going on then. I have my function and code as shown above

Comment: Nobody else knows either. The code you posted would not have that problem. Are you really cutting and pasting the code from your actual source, or are you posting what you think to be a representative sample?

Comment: @Chris Is a property named `antwoord` being set on anything else, at any other place in your code? What happens if you insert `alert(spel);` as the first line in function `start`?

Comment: My spidey senses are telling me there may be a scope issue somewhere if this isn't a full representation of your code.

Comment: @Pointy I'm cutting exactly what I have in my code

Comment: I recommend creating a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm only checking if the property named `antwoord` is `<= 5`. Also, when I `alert(spel);` it shows me undefined.

Comment: @DrewKennedy created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1zy2kqap)

Comment: Welp, as I said, you didn't post all of your code. The `start()` function is **not** called from a window "load" handler, it's called before any of the code you posted.

Comment: @Pointy is right. You're calling start() on the line before spel is defined. Case closed. This fiddle demonstrates a fix: https://jsfiddle.net/nLb70xfk/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, here's the **actual** code taken from the fiddle:

```
(function() {
  document.getElementById('hint').disabled = true;

  start();
})();

var spel = new Object();
var number = document.getElementById('number');



function start() {

  alert(spel);
  spel.antwoord = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  spel.aantalKeer = 0;

  number.value = "";
  document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('hintPos').innerHTML = "";
}
```

The `start()` function is called at the top, inside that immediately-executed anonymous function. That's why `spel` is `undefined`.

In a comment, you said that you expected `start()` to be called from a window "load" handler. To do that, you'd change that initial function from an IIFE to an event handler assignment:

```
window.onload = (function() {
  document.getElementById('hint').disabled = true;

  start();
});

var spel = new Object();
var number = document.getElementById('number');



function start() {

  alert(spel);
  spel.antwoord = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  spel.aantalKeer = 0;

  number.value = "";
  document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('hintPos').innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean now. Looked over the fact that I ran `start()` before defining the object.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this:

```
var spel = {}; // initialize empty object
function start() {
     spel.antwoord = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); // asign a new property
     spel.aantalKeer = 0;

     number.value = "";
     document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = "";
     document.getElementById('hintPos').innerHTML = "";
}
```